# How can I partition by group that falls within a time range?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, range

I have the following table showing when customers bought a certain product. The data I have is `CustomerID, Amount, Dat`. I am trying to create the column `ProductsIn30Days`, which represents how many products a customer bought in the range `Dat-30` days inclusive the current day.

For example, `ProductsIn30Days` for `CustomerID` 1 on `Dat` 25.3.2020 is 7, since the customer bought 2 products on 25.3.2020 and 5 more products on 24.3.2020, which falls within 30 days before 25.3.2020.

| CustomerID | Amount | Dat | ProductsIn30Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23.3.2018 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 24.3.2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 24.3.2020 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 25.3.2020 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 24.5.2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 15.6.2020 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 24.3.2017 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 24.3.2020 | 2 |

I tried something like this with no success, since the partition only works on a single date rather than on a range like I would need:

```
select CustomerID, Amount, Dat,
sum(Amount) over (partition by CustomerID, Dat-30)
from table
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an analytic `SUM` function with a range window:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(Amount) OVER (
         PARTITION BY CustomerID
         ORDER BY Dat
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS ProductsIn30Days
FROM   table_name t;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (CustomerID, Amount, Dat) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2018-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2020-03-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, DATE '2020-03-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2020-03-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2020-05-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2020-06-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 7, DATE '2017-03-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, DATE '2020-03-24' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMERID | AMOUNT | DAT | PRODUCTSIN30DAYS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 2018-03-23 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 1 | 2 | 2020-03-24 00:00:00 | 5 |
> | 1 | 3 | 2020-03-24 00:00:00 | 5 |
> | 1 | 2 | 2020-03-25 00:00:00 | 7 |
> | 1 | 2 | 2020-05-24 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 1 | 1 | 2020-06-15 00:00:00 | 3 |
> | 2 | 7 | 2017-03-24 00:00:00 | 7 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2020-03-24 00:00:00 | 2 |

*Note: If you have values on the same date then they will be tied in the order and always aggregated together (i.e. rows 2 & 3). If you want them to be aggregated separately then you need to order by something else to break the ties but that would not work with a `RANGE` window.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=692bbefeac9b5898ba1c48d71b08bc4e)*

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I got the error 01873. 00000 -  "the leading precision of the interval is too small"  when I tried to use a larger interval (200 days). I was able to fix that by changing `INTERVAL '200' DAY` to `INTERVAL '200' DAY(3)`.

Comment: @Dudelstein Yes, that is the correct syntax to fix that leading precision issue.